# Why I got this strange errors when compiling assembly code using nasm?

Tags: assembly, nasm

Test platform is Linux 32 bit.

I use

```
nasm -f elf final.s
```

to assemble the code, and it generate these errors:

```
final.s:40454: error: (at:1) `%$strucname': context stack is empty
final.s:40454: error: (at:1) `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
final.s:40454: error: (at:1) `%$strucname': context stack is empty
final.s:40454: error: (at:1) `%$strucstart': context stack is empty
final.s:40454: error: expecting `)'
final.s:40454: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
```

And here is part of my code:

```
40451
40452 byte_4092CA     db 89h, 0FFh
40453 off_415E82      dd $LN119
40454 aT              db 'T',0
```

40454 is the **last line** of my code.

I have not seen this kind of error and after a quick google, I can not find any useful stuff.

Could anyone give me some help? Thank you!

--------------update--------------

I tried to put this line of code to other places, but same errors..., which means it is not some issues with **last line**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"at" is a keyword used to initialize a structure. Apparently, Nasm is (very!) confused when you use it as a symbol. I thought I knew Nasm pretty well, but this is a new one on me! Just call your variable something else - `_aT` seems to work...